# SP Designer Workflow Editor - Removing Duplicate User Account

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-server, sharepoint-foundation

When working on a workflow in SP Designer 2010 I've got a specific user that shows up as having two different domain accounts. Both display the same name but clicking each of them shows a different account such as: DOMAIN\admin_dsmith and DOMAIN\dsmith. How can I remove one of the accounts?

[image]

If I do a search from the site using the people picker, only one of the accounts shows. Also, when I go into the Central Admin / User Profiles and search I can only find one.  Where is the Designer workflow editor getting the duplicate names from? Is there any way I can remove on of them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This user most likely has an "admin" account in an OU that is not synchronized to the SharePoint UPS, this is why both accounts are not showing up when you look under Central Admin / User Profiles.